# Repercussions of enabling useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, clr4.0

For my current project, we're using some CLR 2 based mixed mode assemblies.

In order to use these from within a .NET 4 targetted assembly, I know you have to add `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=true` to the [`<startup>` element within app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h(VS.100).aspx).

I understand that this changes the activation policy, causing these mixed-mode assemblies to be loaded using the highest supported version of the CLR.

However, are there any side effects to doing this?  What potential issues should I watch for when enabling the non-default activation policy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config

Comment: Not a duplicate of that - I understand what it's doing - and tried to explicitly state that.  I'm wondering if there are any other side effects from enabling this behavior, since it's application (not assembly) wide...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sure, you'll be running the app with a CLR version it has never been tested against.  Microsoft does a great job keeping it backwards compatible.  But the case of Microsoft managers losing email access for a few days after a .NET upgrade is famous.  The threadpool timing was slightly different, exposing a threading race in a program written by an intern.  Can't google the link right now.

Answer (score 12):

Hans Passant is partially correct. I attempt to explain this enigmatic attribute in this blog entry: http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,ecc34c3c-be44-4422-86b7-900900e451f9.aspx

The repercussions are essentially that you lock out in-proc SxS with pre-v4 runtimes.  This is typically acceptable in a migration scenario.