# Communication between .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 application

Tags: c#-2.0, c#-4.0

I have an application (an STA EXE) which is developed in .Net 2.0 has the provided some hooks so that one can write plug-ins. I planned to write a plug-in in .Net 4.0, which will be a dll. Please let me know what is the best way to do two way communication between these two application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're referencing the projects between each other, but you may run into this error:

[What does ‘useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy’ do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)