# Video chat / conference SDK for .NET that WORKS?

Tags: .net, wpf, video, chat, conference

After googling and binging for a whole day about this, and even trying some stuff unsuccessfully, I'm giving up, to ask you guys this question -

**Is there on this planet a viable, downloadable SDK for .NET which one can use, *out of the box*, to add IP to IP (peer to peer) video conference / chat (or whatever people call it) to one's .NET, C# application???**

That's exactly where I stand, and I need one ASAP. I have a WPF application that's waiting only for that missing link.

(I've tried AVSPEED's solution, doesn't work with my .NET framework 4 app, so I need something else)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution :

[What does 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

just open your app.config, add the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute as shown below :

This is necessary because the iConf.NET SDK makes use mixed-mode assemblies.

We have also sent you this via email -

Regards

AVSPEED, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for quite a lot  OOTB :-)

[Jabber.net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) might help you build a p2p conf./IMing solution very easily. GTalk and Facebook  chat both XMPP (the Jabber protocol). Video conferencing is a bit trickier, the [Jingle](http://psi-im.org/wiki/Jingle_branch) set of extensions offer a promising set of video/audio extensions to Jabber.