# SMO not available in .NET 4.0? Or is there an easier way to backup a database from code

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0, smo

We upgraded our application to .NET 4.0 a while ago, and now need to add the ability to backup SQL Server 2008 databases from the app.  However, it doesn't seem that SMO is available for .NET 4.  Is there a workaround or better way to perform a database backup (note that our backups need to be user initiated over a website, so we cannot schedule them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)?

Otherwise, try these [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

Comment: We'd also need to handle restoring a database as well ... is it easier to just call the SQL commands via a Connection?  We were concerned about handling problems/exceptions.

Comment: TRY/CATCH and RESTORE DATABASE?

Comment: Cool, I had no idea you could do a try/catch within T-SQL

Answer (score 2):

You can still reference SMO from a .NET 4.0 application, even with it targeting the .NET 2.0 framework.

If you get the `Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
configuration information.` exception, installing the latest version of the SQL Server SDK (SQL Server 2008 R2) should fix it, even if the machine is running an older version of SQL Server e.g. 2005.

Comment: You can vote for 4.0 support for SMO here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/643811/net-4-0-compatible-smo