# Migrate Visual Studio 2008 project to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi i want to move Visual Studio 2008 C#.NET project to Visual Studio 2010. My existing VS2008 project Solution have multiple projects.My vs2010 is a WPF project , i moved some core project VS2008 to VS2010 WPF project. Successfully convert and added into VS2010 project but i am not able to reference converted project.

Comment: The first "feature" is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config

Comment: You should be able to open your 2008 project right in 2010 and just keep using it.  This is a comment 'cuz I'm not 100% certain.  It worked for my projects.  A little wizard pops up, you click next a lot and you should be set.

Comment: You changed the question from when I answered it.  Make sure all projects are targeting the same framework version.  Right click the project and go to properties.  I'm betting your old apps are still in the .net 2 or 3.5 framework version, while the new app is using the .net 4.0 framework version (by default).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just open the project in Visual studio 2010.  It will prompt you before it upgrades.  I recommend making a backup (there is a checkbox in the upgrade wizard).  Just follow the instructions in the wizard.  It is fairly straightforward.

The upgrade only changes the solution/project file.  You can still have the app be a .net 2.0 or 3.5 application by choosing the target framework in the project properties.  When you upgrade to 4.0, however, is when you will need to do lots of regression testing.  We upgraded an MVC 1.0 app to .net 4.0 and had problems with the [renderpartialtostring](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/) approach.  We had to rewrite portions of the app just to upgrade into 4.0.

Also, don't forget that if you upgrade a project, certain behavior of the newer version will be suppressed by means of property sheets. You can get back the proper (new) behavior by removing the `InheritedPropertySheets` element of each `Configuration` in the `.vcproj` files.