# MSBuild Task that build the same project (itself), but for a different CLR version (4.0)

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, clr

I have a project that is currently building in .NET 3.5 (CLR 2.0), and I want to upgrade to .NET 4.0 (CLR 4.0), but there are folks dependent on my project that are going to be loading the DLL in a 2.0 process.

So I'm thinking of using the MSBuild task to make two copies of my dlls, one for CLR 2.0 and one for CLR 4.0.

Any other good suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, trying to solve people-problems with build-settings.  That's been known to not work.  Make a compelling case to the boss, ask how to do that at programmers.

Comment: Since you'd be constrained to .NET 3.5 features anyway, what benefit do you expect from having a .NET 4 version?

Comment: You can look at setting the targetRuntime in the assembly. Did you look at the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy.. Take a look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config