# Program Stopped working, Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I am starting my program from release folder. On my Windows 7 64-bit machine it is working.

In virtual machine Windows 7 32-bit it is working.

On third machine with Windows 7 64-bit it is not working.

On every machine I have installed .NET Framework 4, my project use .NET Framework 3.5 because I use SQLite database, and SQLite dll as I understand need for project to be .NET Framework 3.5.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition, SQLite database.

Here is error from third computer:

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   geotest.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   4e58f462
Problem Signature 04:   GeoTest
Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4e58f462
Problem Signature 07:   f
Problem Signature 08:   12
Problem Signature 09:   System.BadImageFormatException
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In release folder there is no System.Data.SQLite.DLL, that was problem. Now when i copy it everything is working.

Answer (score 8):

The Common Language Runtime from version 3.0 onward uses a different method to load a mixed-mode assembly (one containing both managed *and* native code) like SQLite.  Since SQLite was built against the .NET Framework 2.0, we have to specifically tell the CLR to use the old 2.0 way of loading mixed-mode assemblies:

Add (or update) app.config in your project:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Other questions also reveal more information on this: [SQLite-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode-a) / [generic explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

Comment: I had a similar problem. Your solution did well for me. Thanks a lot for your help. :)