# Windows Application has stopped working in client Machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crash, systemmanagement

I developed an applicatin using Visual Studio 2013 and made a Setup Exe file for my application and installed on client machines where they have both Windows7 gives exception.

But when i install and run this application (exe) file in development machine its installed and run correctly. Only on Client's machine its installed correctly but not running, giving the error when double clicking on the exe file.

I have installed Freamwork 4.0 full & Freamwork 4.5 and run Application with Admin rights.

**Description:**

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:   hard disk protector.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02: 1.0.5967.31113
>
> Problem Signature 03: 57288fba
>
> Problem Signature 04: System.Management
>
> Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.17929
>
> Problem Signature 06:   4ffa5bd3
>
> Problem Signature 07:   da
>
> Problem Signature 08:   3f
>
> Problem Signature 09:   System.Management.Management
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:  1033
>
> Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

[image]

How can i resolve it....

Comment: Have you tried to add to the config file for legacy stuff:  like in first answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263610/program-stopped-working-problem-event-nameclr20r3?rq=1

Comment: its not working for me...

Comment: I think its not a duplicate question because my problem with System.Management.Management, unlike system.argumentexception which you told as duplicate.

Comment: @DurgeshPandey Can you post the App.Config

Comment: @CathalMF <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a dependant DLL somewhere.

Compare your "working" directory on your development machine to the "not working" directory on your client machine. Any DLL's missing?

Comment: OK, but in development machine has install total Visual Studio which has all component. And which components are necessary those i already install in client machine.

Comment: But your obviously missing something, so you cannot say that you have copied all necessary components.