# .NET 4 vs .NET 3.5 C# application. Could not load file or assembly 'x' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, interop, c++-cli

I have a C# WPF application built in VS 2010 with Target Platform set to x86. This exe calls on a Managed DLL with target platform ANYCPU.  The Managed DLL has a reference to a C++ DLL which is compiled with Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) option.

On .NET 3.5 the app works perfectly with on any OS. It works fine on Win 7 as well, on both 32bit and 64 bit.

Now that I have converted the application and its DLLs to target .NET 4. If it is run on a .NET less than 4, it throws an error that .NET 4 is required which is the expected result.

The converted app works fine on my development system and on any system that has .NET 4 + .NET 3.5. So far so good!

However, on systems with ONLY .NET 4 (ie Win 8) or win 7 without .NET 3.5, I get the error:
Could not load file or assembly 'x' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

'x' is the C++ dll compiled with Language Runtime Support (/clr) option.

So, in short the problem only happens on systems with .NET 4 only.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you,
- Kam

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4 has back compatibility with all previous versions. So it doesn't seem the problem is in the platform version. Might it be folder's security? Try to check its permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have admin right for the folder. I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in native code loading policies since .NET 4. To resolve this, please add the App.config file to your .exe project with the following contents:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This discussion may also help: [What does 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

Comment: My app.config file does have this setting. So, the problem must be somthing else.