# Unable to retrieve configuration setting values from azure Service configuration file

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, webrole

I am unable to retrieve configuration setting values from Azure service configuration file.

**I am able to run the application in local machine but after uploading the package into the azure site. Then while browing the application it is throwing the error.**
I tried to read the values in the below two ways.

```
public readonly static string CONNECTIONSTRING = Decrypt.DecryptMsg(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString"));
```

and

```
public readonly static string CONNECTIONSTRING = Decrypt.DecryptMsg(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString"));
```

It is throwing an error that

> Exception Occurred ::The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an
>   exception"

Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Take a look here and see if this solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560053/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-windowsazure-serviceruntime-roleenvironment

Comment: No Gaurav, It is not working. The main thing here is, I am able to run the application in my local machine by selecting the azure project solution as start up project. After uploading the package into azure site, I am getting this error. Please help me in solving this error as this error occuring from last one month.