# .net 4.5 service reference won't reuse 4.0 types

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5, generator

In a .net 4.5 project I'm trying to create a WCF service reference that reuses types compiled in .net 4.0, but I can't get Visual Studio to reuse the 4.0 types in the service proxy.

I can instantiate the types just fine, but the service reference generator refuses to pick them up. If I add the same service to a .net 4.0 project, the types are successfully reused.

Does anybody know how to get a .net 4.5 generated service proxy to reuse .net 4.0 types?

Comment: When you say refuses does that throw any error or warning?

Comment: No errors or warnings. The service proxy generates just fine, but it doesn't reuse any types.

Comment: If you have a direct reference to your service contract I would recommend you forego using VS Add Service Reference. I personally always directly use `ChannelFactory` when I control both Client and Server side.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it has anything to do with `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`. I'm not sure if this will help your issue in WCF, but try sticking this in your .config file

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Detailed a bit better here: [What does 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SvcUtil` command line with `/r`tag

```
SvcUtil http://localhost/Service.svc /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /r:"..\Reference Assemblies\Service.DataContracts.dll"
```

`/r` with `SvcUtil` adds the specified assembly to the set of assemblies used for resolving type references. If you are exporting or validating a service that uses 3rd-party extensions (Behaviors, Bindings and BindingElements) registered in configuration, use this option to locate extension assemblies that are not in the GAC.

For more details, refer [msdn SvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

Make sure referenced dll are in physical location from where it is refernced, works for me.
Hope it will help you.