# Failed to load C module in new appdomain

Tags: c#, com, appdomain

I have some .NET code that need to run in a separate AppDomain, and everything goes well except when there is call of COM component.
To make it clear, I wrote a very simple repro as below:

```
AppDomain ap = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newap");
ap.DoCallBack(
    () =>
    {
        //GroupPolicyObject is from assembly microsoft.grouppolicy.management.interop.dll
        GroupPolicyObject newGPO = new GroupPolicyObject();
    });
```

The exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   '' threw an exception. --->
>   .ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed
>   to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.  --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid operation.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131022)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   .GetDefaultDomain()    at
>   .DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function,
>   Void* cookie)    at
>   .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )    at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   .ThrowModuleLoadException(String
>   errorMessage, Exception innerException)    at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )    at .cctor()

The code can pass in default domain, and should not be the issue related with the version of .NET framework.

I did a lot of searching in the internet, but there’s no useful solution. Does anyone have ideas what’s the issue and how to achieve this?

Comment: Just because it works in the default AppDomain doesn't imply that it's not due to the .NET Framework version. Try creating an isolated reproducer, and try both .NET 2.0 and 4.0.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried both, but the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last I fixed it by adding

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
```

in the cofig file.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config) is quite useful.