# ModuleLoadException on calling a method from object

Tags: c#, c++

While calling any method from a dll class am getting bellow exception

```
 LateConnector.Connector obj = new LateConnector.Connector();
 obj.Connect();
```

Am getting exception as

```
[ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.
]
   <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) +170
   .cctor() +28
```

I have tried by **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy** but didnt work.

This dll is in a class library and am accessing it from a mvc application
My application is in .net 4.0

Comment: Have you tried running [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) on the C++ module being loaded in? If it has references to other C++ modules that are unavailable you will get a module load exception.

Comment: Have you done **both** these things? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138825/34092

Comment: @lcs it is working properly if I run in console application , but not in web application

Comment: @mjwills yes I tried this too but no help