# following feature couldn't be installed on .NETframework 3.5

Tags: c++, .net, windows-8, .net-framework-version

I have managed C++ Dll (compiled using clr option)and I am calling it from unmanaged C++ console application.It is working fine,but it is not working fine in Window 2012 where .Net 4.5 is installed.

I have not Installed .Net 3.5 in Window 2012 machine.I am getting prompt as "following feature couldn't be installed on .NETframework 3.5.

1. Win32C++ App
2. ManagedDll

I followed this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and created app config file ManagedDll.dll.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

It is not working and dll load is failing with window error 1114/ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED.

It should work without Installing .Net 3.5. Do I need to install Net3.5 in Window 2012machine?

Can App config file be used for dll as well ??

**UPDATED1:**

I tried with simple managed c++ application along with app config file,still problem remains.

NetSample1.exe
NetSample1.exe.config

**UPDATED2**

I tried C# windows forms application.It didn't worked without app.exe.config and it is working with app.exe.

Now it seems configuration file is not at all consulted while loading dll.

Comment: Shouldn't 3.5 be installed on Windows Server 2012 automatically...?

Comment: No It won't be Installed.However one can Install it by checking the check box in Turn on/off windows program.

Comment: Ah, right, it needs to be installed as a "Feature", I remember. Is there a special reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The app will go to user.We want to avoid user doing these things. Infact app config should suppose to do that automatically.I don't know if naming convention for config file is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
         <supportedRuntime version="v2.0"/>
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
       </startup>
  </configuration>
```