# useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" does not work with .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.5, mixed-mode

The Top answers here: [What does 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' do in the .NET 4 config?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1604663/44080) and [What 'additional configuration' is necessary to reference a .NET 2.0 mixed mode assembly in a .NET 4.0 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode/16126870#16126870) did not help.

My particular Use-case is .Net 4.5 and above for WinForms and Console apps in `VS2015`, while trying to use a `.net 2.0 dll`

Under VS2015, adding the suggested variants of this to projects config file does not help.

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:

The .net 2.0 library depends on an external, non-dotnet dll.

In .net 4.0 client mode and .net 4.0 Full mode it works as expected.

But for .net 4.5 and above the functionality in that library stops working, even though the application starts up.

Comment: @leppie this is a VS2015 issue, and isn't it mixed-mode related?

Comment: It has nothing to do with VS. It is .NET runtime. Mixed-mode is related to assemblies with native and managed code. You might actually want to describe what does not work, and what goes wrong, maybe.

Comment: @leppie thanks. see my updated question

Comment: @CharlesO "functionality stops working" isn't descriptive enough to determine.  It sounds like it's a different issue - the library will fail at binding time with exceptions if the runtime policy is wrong.  On a separate note, you shouldn't have the 2nd runtime line in your file, only `v4.0`

Comment: @leppie This is what i have tried: with .net 4.0 there are no issues. Once i move to 4.5 I still don't have any run-time errors, but the function calls to the 2.0 library begin to give incorrect results. Because there are no errors thrown, I am unable to describe my situation any further.

Comment: What are these 'incorrect results'?

Comment: @leppie for example the 2.0 library in question is for a fingerprint reader. One of its basic function calls enumerates all the Fingerprint readers attached to your machine. This always returns nothing for .net 4.5, but gives expected results on .net 4.0 and below.

Comment: Remove `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>`, if you program is compiled for 4.5, it will use it automatically. Alternatively, try `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />`

Comment: Tried both variants... on .net4.5 same result, not working.

Comment: @leppie other who reported similar claimed it had to do with their Test project and they fixed it by making the config adjustments in some None-Project folders elsewhere. sadly those fixes do not apply to my case, for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16126870/44080

Comment: :*( IS it possible for you to debug the mixed mode assembly? (Also retagged, as mixed-mode is actually relevant here)

Comment: @leppie I can try to remove "just my code" feature, but the 3rd part dll is a library from the fingerprint reader vendor.