# Automatically update SQL Server database schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, clickonce, database-schema, auto-update

I have deployed a C# app and my customers benefits from new deployed versions by ClickOnce update.

But I have trouble when I change to the application database schema because the customers cannot benefit from auto update database changes, please give me the solution how can I let customer app to check if the new version of DB is available then do the update.

So there are two problems:

1. how does customer app check for DB schema new version?
2. how to perform update with avoid to loss customer data just update schema?

Comment: What technology do you use to access database? What schema changes do you plan to apply? What database do you use?

Comment: It is sql DB (sql server 2008 r2).
I mean change in field name or adding new tables ,stored proc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume each user has it own database. In this case you can do the following:

1. use Entity Framework with "auto migrations" enabled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx. This way as soon as model change is detected, EF will automatically update database.
2. Write migrations manually and use [ClickOnce IsFirstRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) feature to detect the first time when new version of the app was executed - and then you can write something like this:

> ```
> public void MigrateData()
> {
>   if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
>   {
>       if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
>       {
>           try
>           {
>               NS.Logic.DAL.EventDataAccessor.Create().MigrateFromPreviousVersion();
>               NS.Logic.DAL.UserDataAccessor.Create().MigrateFromPreviousVersion();
>               // and do the same for all affected accessors
>           }
>           catch (Exception ex)
>           {
>               MessageBox.Show("Could not migrate data from previous version. Please contact the developer.",
>                   "My app", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
>           }
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

and then for each accessor in MigrateFromPreviousVersion() you write your own SQL code to update the database for this particular version of the app.

Comment: you need to create SQL code which does the migration (i.e. "CREATE PROCEDURE ..." etc) - and execute it inside `MigrateFromPreviousVersion()` call. If you use ADO.Net - this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1190832/1246870

Comment: basically, it's YOUR responsibility now to track all changes you do in database, and keep them in a separate folder - so you can combine them into "deployment" package when releasing new app version.

Comment: re: MainDATASET.xsd - no idea sorry - that was not your initial question - do some SO search for that.